# Joomla - swallow a JError::raiseError-Message silently

Tags: error-handling, joomla, joomla1.5

Hey guys,
is it possible to catch and ignore a JError::raiseError?
I use JDatabase and if a user acts 'stupid' a duplicate entry can occur.
But that's not a problem and can be ignored silently.

Unfortunatelly this error is printed over the hole page. Now i dont want to
drop a new query just to check if this primary key already exists.

Comment: Found the solution. System debugging was activated. After deactivating it in the Configuration-Settings the error wasn't shown anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable throwing of Joomla exceptions in the execution path call:

`JError::setErrorHandling(E_ALL, "ignore");`

Alternative you can set your own custom handler:

JError::setErrorHandling(E_ALL, 'callback', array('myClass', 'myErrorHandlerFunction'));

Comment: Above statement "There is NO ESCAPE from raiseError" is incorrect. JExit is only called if no error handler can be found. For example by passing an invalid class/function to SetErrorHandling.

Answer (score 1):

There is NO ESCAPE from raiseError

Below is Joomla's raise method. As you can see it uses **jexit** which calls php **[exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)**

```
function & raise($level, $code, $msg, $info = null, $backtrace = false)
{
    jimport('joomla.error.exception');

    // build error object
    $exception = new JException($msg, $code, $level, $info, $backtrace);

    // see what to do with this kind of error
    $handler = JError::getErrorHandling($level);

    $function = 'handle'.ucfirst($handler['mode']);
    if (is_callable(array('JError', $function))) {
        $reference =& JError::$function ($exception, (isset($handler['options'])) ? $handler['options'] : array());
    } else {
        // This is required to prevent a very unhelpful white-screen-of-death
        jexit(
            'JError::raise -> Static method JError::' . $function . ' does not exist.' .
            ' Contact a developer to debug' .
            '<br /><strong>Error was</strong> ' .
            '<br />' . $exception->getMessage()
        );
    }

    //store and return the error
    $GLOBALS['_JERROR_STACK'][] =& $reference;
    return $reference;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's totally correct. I had a look into the JDatabase::query method and found that the Error is only raised if _debug is set. So i had a look into my configuration and saw that i had system debugging turned on... ups :) sorry for the circumstances

Answer (score 1):

if overwriting the existing row doesn't matter you could use

```
REPLACE INTO 'table' set 'field'=1 etc etc
```

[MYSQL REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Which will create a row or replace an existing one. That should make it so no error is raised at all if the row exists.

Comment: yup that's correct. Thanks. I already found another solution for my problem. just had to turn of the debug messages. ups ^^